# Python selenium error after long runtime

Tags: python, selenium, fsevents

Was running my selenium python code and came across a strange error:

```
Python[367] (FSEvents.framework) implementation_callback_rpc: ERROR: CFDictionaryGetValue(FSEvents_streamDict, cfPortNumber) => NULL
```

I searched around but I couldn't find what this error means. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's the code where the error is, but it seems like something more general occurred:

```
#Go to next page
next_button[0].click()
# Wait until next page has loaded
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value(
        (By.ID,"MainContent_GridView1_PageCurrent"),`page_count+1`)
)
```

Here's the full error message:

```
2015-01-13 18:21 Python[510] (FSEvents.framework) implementation_callback_rpc: ERROR: CFDictionaryGetValue(FSEvents_streamDict, cfPortNumber) => NULL
2015-01-13 18:28 Python[510] (FSEvents.framework) implementation_callback_rpc: ERROR: CFDictionaryGetValue(FSEvents_streamDict, cfPortNumber) => NULL
2015-01-13 18:36 Python[510] (FSEvents.framework) implementation_callback_rpc: ERROR: CFDictionaryGetValue(FSEvents_streamDict, cfPortNumber) => NULL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "epa_interns.py", line 145, in <module>
    print(main_process(44))
  File "epa_interns.py", line 36, in main_process
    PDF_count = download_pdfs_for_state(driver,state_number,download_folder)
  File "epa_interns.py", line 72, in download_pdfs_for_state
    (By.ID,"MainContent_GridView1_PageCurrent"),`page_count+1`
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: I don't know about the original error message, but the full message looks like a failure to find the attribute that you're looking for.

Comment: The error is from the until function. The given text is not present in the specified element locator you provided. To be sure, try to change the time from 20 to 10 and see if you get that exception after 10 seconds.